# Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I setting up a addRole commands and this command works but if someone type only "!rbu" without member, bot gets error.

Maybe force a person to make the code work, they must enter the person, but how im pretty new at this

````
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch(args[0]){
   case'rbu':

case'rbu':

if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "GroupI")) return message.channel.send('You cant do that')

let memberToModify = message.mentions.members.first();
var roleToAdd = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "GroupII");
memberToModify.addRole(roleToAdd);

break;

    }
  }
)


I expect this to do nothing or message that member must type !rbu and user

memberToModify.addRole(roleToAdd)
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've got 2 `case'rbu':` which is weird. Then, you need to make sure that the message actually mentions, with the `message.mentions` propriety, like so:

```
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch(args[0]){
   case'rbu':

    if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "GroupI") || !message.mentions) return
message.channel.send('You cant do that')

    let memberToModify = message.mentions.members.first();
    var roleToAdd = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "GroupII");
    memberToModify.addRole(roleToAdd);

break;
}
```